# Can a porcelain sink be fired again to repair surface cracks?

Tags: sink, porcelain

I have a very large pedestal bathroom sink that has some micro cracks in the glazing.  The cracks are around the drain plug.  I think this damage occurred before I purchased the home by the owner tightening the joint too tight.  It is an expensive sink and I hate the idea of putting it in the trash, but it is getting impossible to keep those cracks free of dirt.

If I can find a local place that has a big enough kiln, can the sink basin be fired again to repair the cracks, or another layer of glaze applied, then fired?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, yes. But with any refiring, there's a chance of introducing new defects, like bubbling and so forth. The larger the piece, the more difficult it is to ensure all of it heats up uniformly. Otherwise you'll get more cracks than you started with. I have no experience with commercial services doing what you ask for on this scale (bathroom sink), but apparently [some exist](http://ths.gardenweb.com/discussions/2513282/refiring-or-reporcelaining-vintage-sinks-yes-it-can-be-done).

Answer (score 0):

A more reasonable repair would be to use epoxy. There is an epoxy product for refinishing lavatories. My thought would be to clean the cracks and then recoat the area of the cracks. Color matching would be a problem; perhaps if you could clean the cracks completely you could use colorless epoxy.

**EDIT**

There are abrasive pastes for polishing glass, some are diamond dust in a mineral oil vehicle, which could probably be used to grind away the cracked glass finish down to the porcelain. Then coat with epoxy.

Comment: These cracks are just in the glaze coating. No chipping at all. Picture your grandma's old China plates.